# Display colored zip-based regions on Power BI map

Tags: kml, bing-maps, powerbi

I have KML data that contains the lat/lon of the boundaries (polygons) that define Zip Code regions in the US.  I'd like display these polygons with different colors (that represent some metric in my customer data) on a MS Power BI map widget.

How does the data (polygons and associated metrics) need to be prepared for this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called Shape Maps in Power BI.  As of the August 2016 release it's still in Preview only.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-shape-map

You need to get your data into TopoJSON format - the article suggests an online tool that might help.